# Why is Typescript not raising an error for missed arguments?

Tags: typescript

I have the following code:

```
type Callback = (a: string, b: string) => void

const observer: Callback = function(a: string): void {
  console.log(a)
}

observer('foo')
```

Typescript is complaining on the last line:

```
Expected 2 arguments, but got 1.(2554)
```

Why is TS only complaining on the observer call instead of doing that on line 3 where the observer is implemented?

Playground link: http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=7&ssc=16&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAwghgGwQIzgYwNZQLxQBRwBcUAzsAE4CWAdgOYA0UyxZVdAlDgHxQBuA9pQAmAKBFp+1MlH7ISEcrwXF4SVJhxQAZgFdqaYJUkEWFGrXbEBwqAG8RUKBKn8EEAHQJ+tAuxEBfMVl5RQU8AHItfn5w9iA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They have a section in their documetation discussing this https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#comparing-two-functions

Basically, it's because in javascript it's legal and somewhat common to ignore extra function parameters. For example, The following code claims it takes a `b` parameter, but never does anything with it:

```
const observer: Callback = function(a: string, b: string): void {
  console.log(a);
}
```

Presumably you agree that this should match the `Callback` type definition. But what purpose does `b: string` serve in the argument list? The only effects it has are to change the value of `observer.length`, and to change what's returned by `observer.toString()`. In practice, it's just a waste of typing in most cases.

As a realworld case of this, arrays have several higher order functions such as `.map`, `.filter`, `.reduce`. You pass in a function to it to control what the behavior is. Your function will get passed in several pieces of data, but in many cases you only need one. So the following should not be flagged as a type error:

```
const numbers = [1, 2, 3];
const biggerNumbers = numbers.map(value => value + 1);
```

Your function actually gets passed in a value, an index, and the array. But it's ok for you to write code that ignores the last two (or even all 3, though that's rare).

---

In short: The type definition is there to force you to pass certain values **into** the function. It's not there to make sure the function actually **uses** those values.